# Forwarding Loopback Packets to a Physical Network Card

Tags: windows, networking, network-programming

Under Windows XP, SP 3, is it possible to forward loopback packets to a physical network card?

This is one of many attempts I'm making at being able to sniff loopback traffic. The best-looking lead I have so far is to use RawCap, but it's just not grabbing the packets for some unknown reason (I have another post on this topic).

Also, I'll note that Windows Loopback Adapter (WLA) is not a solution for me. The traffic I'm trying to catch is on 127.0.0.1. WLA requires an address other than 127.0.0.1 be used.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set any IP that you want to microsoft loopback adapter.

You can use Wireshark / winpcap and monitor the loopback adapter itself.